Omitting object key causes subsequent plans to always return changes
Given that I have TF file like:
resource "fusionauth_application" "test" {
  tenant_id = fusionauth_tenant.test_frontend.id
  application_id = var.fusionauth_test_application_id
  name      = var.fusionauth_test_application_name

  jwt_configuration {
    enabled = true
    access_token_id = fusionauth_key.test-rsa-access-token.key_id
  }
}

After first run of the Terraform the resource will be created and that's totally fine. But during creation of the resource, since the ID token key was not provided, the new ID key will be created for JWT configuration.
Then the subsequent calls to the Terraform apply will always try to set null for jwt_configuration.id_token_key_id
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # fusionauth_application.formedia will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "fusionauth_application" "test" {
        id                                         = <some-id>
        name                                       = "Test"
        # (16 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ jwt_configuration {
          - id_token_key_id           = <some-key> -> null # always shows up
            # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)
        }

        # (4 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }

I'm not sure if this is some bug in the Terraform provider or maybe I should somehow handle this. I cannot/don't really want to explicitly pass the value there, but maybe I should.
EDIT: https://github.com/FusionAuth/terraform-provider-fusionauth/issues/184

it could be a bug you should report it to the provider... but if you just want to ignore that look into lifecycle ignore_changes https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes
